# Log4j1.x migration to log4j2 java

Tags: java, logging, jboss, migration, log4j2

I have upgraded log4j1.x version to log4j2.17, I observed that some of new logs are printing on my console/server.log which might be from other jars I am using (e.g updating server status in database)

How can I restrict stdout in my console or server.log

I have added console appender in my log4j2.xml

Comment: What version of WildFly or JBoss EAP are you using?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins jboss eap 7.3

Comment: What other log4j dependencies do you include in your deployment? Do you want all logs from your deployment to be logged via log4j2?

Answer (score 0):

While this looks like a *bad idea* - you would want important logs from dependencies to be a part of your log for debugging issues, here is the way to do it.

In `log4j.properties` file, you can set the root logger to ERROR. Then for the your own application, you can override the now default ERROR to INFO/DEBUG.

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout
log4j.X.Y.Z=DEBUG
```

Ref - [Filtering out log4j messages from third-party frameworks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569395/filtering-out-log4j-messages-from-third-party-frameworks)